# MySQL & PHP Error Decimal Values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error:

Error: INSERT INTO `Ceny` (`Umowy_idUmowy`, `Cena1`, `Cena2`, `Cena3`, `Cena4`, `Cena5`, `Cena6`, `Cena7`, `Cena8`, `Cena9`, `Cena10`) VALUES (2, 234, 90, 120, 60, 15, , , , , );
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to **use near ' , , , )**' at line 1

Cena1, Cena2 etc. are decimal values.

This is my code:

```
function add_prices($mysql, $idUmowy, $cena1, $cena2, $cena3, $cena4, $cena5, $cena6, $cena7, $cena8, $cena9, $cena10) 
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO `Ceny` (`Umowy_idUmowy`, `Cena1`, `Cena2`, `Cena3`, `Cena4`, `Cena5`, `Cena6`, `Cena7`, `Cena8`, `Cena9`, `Cena10`) VALUES ($idUmowy, $cena1, $cena2, $cena3, $cena4, $cena5, $cena6, $cena7, $cena8, $cena9, $cena10);";

  if ($mysql->query($query) === TRUE)
  {
    return;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'Error: ' . $query . '<br>' . $mysql->error;
    return;
  }
}
```

Please guys HELP :-)

Schema structure:[MySql Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAKos.png)

Schema Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klusek73_umowy`.`Ceny` (
  `idCeny` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Umowy_idUmowy` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `Cena1` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena2` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena3` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena4` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena5` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena6` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena7` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena8` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena9` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Cena10` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCeny`, `Umowy_idUmowy`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idCeny_UNIQUE` (`idCeny` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Ceny_Umowy1_idx` (`Umowy_idUmowy` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Umowy_idUmowy_UNIQUE` (`Umowy_idUmowy` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ceny_Umowy1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Umowy_idUmowy`)
    REFERENCES `klusek73_umowy`.`Umowy` (`idUmowy`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Looks like $cena7, $cena8, $cena9, $cena10 are empty...

Comment: `60, 15, , , , , );`not obvious?

Comment: Yes, and i want it to stay like this. Is it possible?

Comment: use `null` and take a SQL tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much. Decimal values can't be null.

Comment: null is a string value.

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but that's what i read

Comment: Show you Table Schema i.e., Structure

Comment: check the `isset(variable)` for all non null-able fields in you table schema.

Comment: good i've done it

Comment: I think i've got it thantks to you @B.Balamanigandan.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do something like this:

`if ($cena1 === ''){$cena1 = 0}
 if ($cena2 === ''){$cena2 = 0}`

etc...

Thanks for your help. It was about 04:00AM in Poland when I was thinking about it.

Regards,

phpWarrior.